# How do I specify CMake exports macro when building a DLL?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

When building a library on Windows using CMake, I understand I need to mark my classes and functions as `<PROJECT_NAME>_EXPORT` to allow for external libraries to access these.

I am currently doing

```
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(my_project)

target_compile_definitions(my_project PRIVATE my_project_EXPORTS)
set_target_properties(my_project PROPERTIES
            PREFIX ""
            DEFINE_SYMBOL my_project_EXPORTS
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
```

My questions are:

1. Am I doing the correct thing with `target_compile_definitions` and `DEFINE_SYMBOL` if I want to set `my_project_EXPORT` to be `__declspec(dllexport)`, i.e. when building the library?
2. If I am doing the correct thing with the compile definitions, I am not seeing the correct behavior (it is showing up as `dllimport` instead of `dllexport`). Any idea why this may be the case?

Overall, I would really like a step-by-step process of what I would need to do to build my DLL since the resources online have either been scarcely put or are customized to very specific scenarios.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have a full example here: [https://github.com/drescherjm/CMakeLibraryExample/tree/main](https://github.com/drescherjm/CMakeLibraryExample/tree/main)

Comment: this [video by CMake maintainer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0DwB4OvDXk) might help